# The problem of creating a dynamic array and fill random numbers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, void

***I get an error when I want to fill random numbers to Array.
I think the trouble is in the pointers
The error is here ' *ptr[i][j]= rand() % 40000 +5;* '***
Error Name: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int* create_matrix_fill_random (int satir,int sutun);


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Matrix automatically created 3x3");
    int a=3;
    int *matrix = create_matrix_fill_random(a,a);

    return 0;
}

int* create_matrix_fill_random (int row, int col)
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(row*col*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<row;i++){
        for (j=0;j<col;j++){
        ptr[i][j]= rand() % 40000 +5;
    //Mistake ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ 
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: @ArdentCoder Or maybe even `ptr[i + j * col]`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Of course, I was just hinting at the projection of 2D array onto a 1D array. OP could do it in either row-major form or column-major form :)

Comment: @ArdentCoder But your 'formula' is wrong either way! The other option would be `ptr[i * col + j]`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Lol I didn't pay attention to it, using libraries for these kind of tasks made me forget the basics :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a one dimentional array, so you can use only one index.

```
ptr[i * cols + j]= rand() % 40000 +5;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `ptr` within the function has the type `int *`. So applying the subscript operator one time like `ptr[i]` you will get a scalar object of the type `int` for which you may not apply the subscript operator the second time.

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you can write

```
int ( *matrix )[a] = create_matrix_fill_random(a,a);
```

and the function will look like

```
int ( * create_matrix_fill_random (int row, int col) )[]
{
    int ( *ptr )[col];
    ptr = malloc( sizeof( int[row][col] ) );
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<row;i++){
        for (j=0;j<col;j++){
        ptr[i][j]= rand() % 40000 +5;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Otherwise you have to write

```
int **matrix = create_matrix_fill_random(a,a);
```

and the function will look like

```
int ** create_matrix_fill_random (int row, int col)
{
    int **ptr;
    ptr = malloc( sizeof( row * sizeof( int * ) );

    int i,j;

    for ( i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        ptr[i] = malloc( col * sizeof( int ) );
    }

    for (i=0;i<row;i++){
        for (j=0;j<col;j++){
        ptr[i][j]= rand() % 40000 +5;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: @ArdentCoder Maybe there was a typo. I updated the post.

Comment: Fine, another one (silly mistake): Did you forget to remove those code comments indicating the original mistake?

Comment: @Vlad "*If your compiler supports variable length arrays*" - Maybe add the test scenario with checking the value of  macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__`.

Comment: @ArdentCoder Sometimes it is useful to keep those comments to signify the place of the original issue. It´s not a mistake itself.

Comment: @ArdentCoder Thanks. I removed the comment.

Comment: the minus is a weird deallocation procedure especially when one of the allocations fails. Dont like this way. It is better to use index arithmetic to simulate multi dim assays.